# Shell: Execute script commands as different users

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following script:

```
Command1 
Command2
Command3
```

I would like to execute the `command1` and `command2` as user `user1`, and execute the `command3` as `user2`.

That's why this command uses a file that is on the home directory, and each user has it's own. Command 3 requires the User2 file, that's why I need to execute it as user2.

How can I do that?

Comment: Best is to use set-uid bit wrappers.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Well sudo is what you need. If you can install it and have the right to set it up, you'll be able to execute your command with the users you configured.

Your `/etc/sudoers.conf` file will look like somethig like this:

```
user1 ALL = NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/Command1
user1 ALL = NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/Command2
user2 ALL = NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/Command3
```

your script could then be written as:

```
sudo -u user1 Command1
sudo -u user1 Command2
sudo -u user2 Command3
```

Here is a short introduction [to sudo](https://www.linux.com/learn/linux-101-introduction-sudo)